# VBA to click on a button in IE with no ID, Name, ClassName

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, automation

I need to click on a button in IE. I tried few options with no success. Everything i tried are using TagName/ ClassName/ Name/ ID. But I don't find any of these in the below.

```
<FORM method=post name=frmSearch action=searchResultsSummary>
<INPUT type=hidden value=GMT+01:00 name=clitz> 
<DIV style="MARGIN-LEFT: 30px">
<DIV style="MARGIN-BOTTOM: 10px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Common Criteria</DIV>
<TABLE style="MARGIN-LEFT: 20px" cellSpacing=5 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD id=oDocumentCategoryCell style="HEIGHT: 22px" colSpan=3 noWrap>Document category:</TD>
<TD colSpan=3 align=left>
<SELECT style="DISPLAY: block" name=docCategory old_value="2">
<OPTION value=%>Any Category</OPTION>
<OPTION value=FINANCE>Finance Document</OPTION>
<OPTION selected value=INBOUND>Inbound Document</OPTION>
<OPTION value=PROCESS>Internal Process</OPTION>
<OPTION value=OUTBOUND>Outbound Document</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 15px"></TD>
<TD>
<INPUT onclick="javascript:if (!validateSearchForm()) return;if (!checkCountOfDays()) return; addRefKeysToForm(frmSearch); frmSearch.submit();" style="WIDTH: 100px" type=button value=Search>
</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD style="HEIGHT: 22px" colSpan=3 noWrap>Document type:</TD>
<TD colSpan=3 align=left>
<SELECT style="DISPLAY: block" name=docType old_value="0">
<OPTION selected value=%>Any Type</OPTION>
<OPTION value=CSN_ORD_VALID>CSN Order Validation</OPTION>
<OPTION value=CREDIT_ORD>Credit Order</OPTION>
<OPTION value=EOI_ORDCPY>EOI Order Copy</OPTION>
<OPTION value=LEASE_ORD>Lease Order</OPTION>
<OPTION value=ORDER_REPORT>Order Load Report</OPTION>
<OPTION value=TRADE_ORD>Trade Order</OPTION>
<OPTION value=WATSON>WATSON Quote</OPTION>
<OPTION value=WATSON_UPDATE>WATSON Update Quote</OPTION>
<OPTION value=WNGQ>WNGQ Request</OPTION></SELECT> </TD></TR>
<TR>
```

I tried going by input tags and it is not working.

I used the below code. It clicks on the button i want but it is not considering the values i gave before clicking on submit button.

```
Dim btnInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim frm As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set frm = ie.Document.getElementsByName("frmSearch")
For Each btnInput In frm

If btnInput.Value = "frmSearch.submit()" Then
    btnInput.submit
    Exit For
End If
Next btnInput
```

Can some one help me on how to click on the button.

Comment: getElementsByTagName("INPUT")(0)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thank you for the reply... but i tried this already. i have too many buttons in my IE and this input doesn't work.

Comment: You need to change (0) to whatever one it is then. I.e., (1) (2) ... (n)

Comment: Something like `document.querySelector("input[value=Search]")` should work

Answer (score 2):

As @Tim Williams suggest, this should work `document.querySelector("input[value=Search]")`.

If this still doesn't return the correct input element then the selector can be made more specific according to the DOM tree where the searched input is located, e.g. like this.

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Dim inputElement As HTMLInputElement
Set inputElement = doc.querySelector( _
    "div[class=main] div[id=inner] table input[type=button][value=Search]")

If Not inputElement Is Nothing Then
    inputElement.Click
End If
```

> HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="inner">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <INPUT onclick="alert('This is the corect one');" 
                            style="WIDTH: 100px" 
                            type=button 
                            value=Search>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<INPUT onclick="alert('No this is not the searched one');" 
    style="WIDTH: 100px" 
    type=button 
    value=Search>
```

---

EDIT:

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly. 
To select the INPUT element this selector can be used:

```
Set inputElement = doc.querySelector( _
    "form[name=frmSearch] table tbody tr td input[type=button][value=Search]")
```

To set the value attribute `setAttribute()` function can be used. To check value attribute `getAttribute()` function can be used.

```
If Not inputElement Is Nothing Then
    inputElement.setAttribute "value", "some-new-value"
    If inputElement.getAttribute("value") = "some-new-value" Then
        inputElement.Click
    End If
End If
```

Comment: @Sara could you post bigger part of your website? So we can see where the INPUT is located within the DOM tree. And could you describe the problem more precisely? Only info we have so far is 'it is not working'.